# Select names in a MySQLi table

Tags: mysql

Let's assume I have a table with 200 records (to make it easy).

In the table are 10 persons each having 20 records.

I wondered if I should make a 15 columns table, where most of the columns-cells may be blank (= NULL'ed), but I thought I would be better to do it this  way..

Table structure (example):

```
Col0    Col1         Col2        Col3 

ID     Person_Name    Sold_rec.

0      NICK Kerwhaw   date1   ..
1      Paul MCcartney date2   ..
2      John Lennon    date3   .. 
3      Nick Kershaw   date4   ..
4      Paul MCcartney date2   ..
5      John Lennon    date3   .. 
6      Nick Kershaw   date4   ..
7      Paul MCcartney date2   ..
8      John Lennon    date3   ..
```

After the MySQLi select (and result) I want the result for this very simplified table to be:

```
NICK Kerwhaw  
Paul MCcartney  
John Lennon
```

only: (Selecting one name from the 10 groups, ignoring the other(s), and returning the names.

When I have the NAMES as variables I can get the other data (SOLD_REC date) by a simple extraction (That I know how to do).

How Is the syntax in the SELECT COMMAND to get the names:

Comment: When you say "Selecting one name from the 10 groups", what does it mean?

Comment: If I assume that the table contains 10 "John Lennon" records.  I want the SELECT command to in some way to ignore  9 of the 10  "John Lennon' records and return 1 "JL" record  to the result-array. Then same for the rest of the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple you can use the DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause to make the records uniqueness as:

```
select distinct Person_Name from table_name;
```

or

```
select Person_Name from table_name group by Person_Name;
```

Comment: If you find the solution appropriate then you can mark this question answered!

Comment: My God, is it that simple. HAHA , I was told (by a friend of mine) it was a very complicated. But it is not at all . thank you very,very much for giving me that information.